# Query performance issue for large nested data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-performance

I'm trying to query results from a large dataset called *'tasks'* containing **187297 documents** which are nested into another dataset called *'workers'*, that's in its turn nested into a collection called *'production_units'*.

> production_units -> workers -> tasks

(BTW this is a simplified version of production_units):

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("5aca27b926974863ed9f01ab"),
    "name": "Z",
    "workers": [{
        "name": "X Y",
        "worker_number": 655,
        "employed": false,
        "_id": ObjectId("5aca27bd26974863ed9f0425"),
        "tasks": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5ac9f6c2e1a668d6d39c1fd1"),
            "inbound_order_number": 3296,
            "task_number": 90,
            "minutes_elapsed": 120,
            "date": "2004-11-30",
            "start": 1101823200,
            "pieces_actual": 160,
            "pause_from": 1101812400,
            "pause_to": 1101814200
        }]
    }]
}]
```

In order to accomplish this I have used the following aggregation command:

```
db.production_units.aggregate([{
    '$project': {
        'workers': '$workers'
    }
}, {
    '$unwind': '$workers'
}, {
    '$project': {
        'tasks': '$workers.tasks',
        'worker_number': '$workers.worker_number'
    }
}, {
    '$unwind': '$tasks'
}, {
    '$project': {
        'task_number': '$tasks.task_number',
        'pieces_actual': '$tasks.pieces_actual',
        'minutes_elapsed': '$tasks.minutes_elapsed',
        'worker_number': 1,
        'start': '$tasks.start',
        'inbound_order_number': '$tasks.inbound_order_number',
        'pause_from': '$tasks.pause_from',
        'date': '$tasks.date',
        '_id': '$tasks._id',
        'pause_to': '$tasks.pause_to'
    }
}, {
    '$match': {
        'start': {
            '$exists': true
        }
    }
}, {
    '$group': {
        'entries_count': {
            '$sum': 1
        },
        '_id': null,
        'entries': {
            '$push': '$$ROOT'
        }
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'entries_count': 1,
        '_id': 0,
        'entries': 1
    }
}, {
    '$unwind': '$entries'
}, {
    '$project': {
        'task_number': '$entries.task_number',
        'pieces_actual': '$entries.pieces_actual',
        'minutes_elapsed': '$entries.minutes_elapsed',
        'worker_number': '$entries.worker_number',
        'start': '$entries.start',
        'inbound_order_number': '$entries.inbound_order_number',
        'pause_from': '$entries.pause_from',
        'date': '$entries.date',
        'entries_count': 1,
        '_id': '$entries._id',
        'pause_to': '$entries.pause_to'
    }
}, {
    '$sort': {
        'start': 1
    }
}, {
    '$skip': 187290
}, {
    '$limit': 10
}], {
    allowDiskUse: true
})
```

And the returned documents are:

```
{ "entries_count" : 187297, "task_number" : 100, "pieces_actual" : 68, "minutes_elapsed" : 102, "worker_number" : 411, "start" : 1594118400, "inbound_order_number" : 8569, "pause_from" : 1594119600, "date" : "2020-07-07", "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f6d3e1a668d6d3a06351"), "pause_to" : 1594119600 } { "entries_count" : 187297, "task_number" : 130, "pieces_actual" : 20, "minutes_elapsed" : 30, "worker_number" : 549, "start" : 1596531600, "inbound_order_number" : 7683, "pause_from" : 1596538800, "date" : "2020-08-04", "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f6cde1a668d6d39f1b26"), "pause_to" : 1596538800 } { "entries_count" : 187297, "task_number" : 210, "pieces_actual" : 84, "minutes_elapsed" : 180, "worker_number" : 734, "start" : 1601276400, "inbound_order_number" : 8330, "pause_from" : 1601290800, "date" : "2020-09-28", "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f6d0e1a668d6d39fd677"), "pause_to" : 1601290800 } { "entries_count" : 187297, "task_number" : 20, "pieces_actual" : 64, "minutes_elapsed" : 90, "worker_number" : 114, "start" : 1601800200, "inbound_order_number" : 7690, "pause_from" : 1601809200, "date" : "2020-10-04", "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f6cee1a668d6d39f3032"), "pause_to" : 1601811900 } { "entries_count" : 187297, "task_number" : 140, "pieces_actual" : 70, "minutes_elapsed" : 84, "worker_number" : 49, "start" : 1603721640, "inbound_order_number" : 4592, "pause_from" : 1603710000, "date" : "2020-10-26", "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f6c8e1a668d6d39df664"), "pause_to" : 1603712700 } { "entries_count" : 187297, "task_number" : 80, "pieces_actual" : 20, "minutes_elapsed" : 30, "worker_number" : 277, "start" : 1796628600, "inbound_order_number" : 4655, "pause_from" : 1796641200, "date" : "2026-12-07", "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f6c8e1a668d6d39e1fc0"), "pause_to" : 1796643900 } { "entries_count" : 187297, "task_number" : 40, "pieces_actual" : 79, "minutes_elapsed" : 123, "worker_number" : 96, "start" : 3802247580, "inbound_order_number" : 4592, "pause_from" : 3802244400, "date" : "2090-06-27", "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f6c8e1a668d6d39de218"), "pause_to" : 3802244400 }
```

However, the query takes seconds in order to show the results, instead of few milliseconds. This is the result returned by the profiler:

```
 db.system.profile.findOne().millis 3216
```

**(UPDATE)**

Even the following simplified count query gets executed in 312 ms instead of few time:

```
db.production_units.aggregate([{
        "$unwind": "$workers"
    }, {
        "$unwind": "$workers.tasks"
    },
    {
        "$count": "entries_count"
    }
])
```

This is what `explain()` returns for the query above:

```
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {

                },
                "fields" : {
                    "workers" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "my_db.production_units",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {

                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                },
                "executionStats" : {
                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                    "nReturned" : 28,
                    "executionTimeMillis" : 13,
                    "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                    "totalDocsExamined" : 28,
                    "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 28,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 30,
                        "advanced" : 28,
                        "needTime" : 1,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 1,
                        "restoreState" : 1,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "docsExamined" : 28
                    },
                    "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$workers"
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$workers.tasks"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "$const" : null
                },
                "entries_count" : {
                    "$sum" : {
                        "$const" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : false,
                "entries_count" : true
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I'm not an experienced DBA, so I don't know what I'm missing exactly in my aggregation pipeline, for solving the performance issue I'm facing. I have also investigated the problem and made research, but without finding any solution.

What I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried to place the $match at the beginning of your aggregation ? It will reduce the number of documents that pass your different stages

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to achieve with your query, could you add a sample document of your collection, and the expected result ?

Comment: @felix The query concatenates the documents of tasks that are nested for each worker altogether, and then returns the last 10 documents (to fit pagination). Are the posted documents enough, or I need to provide more information?

Comment: @Nicolas Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean exactly. do you mean an empty $match (i.e `$match: {}`)?

Comment: I mean, you can try to put at first time `$match: {"workers.tasks.start": {$exists: true}} to filter the documents you need

Comment: @Nicolas I have just done it. but the aggregation is still slow, and the profiler always showing 3216 milliseconds.

Comment: @Kais please also add a (simplified) document from the `production_units` collection

Comment: @felix I'm so sorry for the delay in responding (I was very busy). I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without the `explain()` of the query it's impossible to know for sure what is the bottleneck of the query. However, here are some advices on how to improve this query

---

### Use a single `$project` stage at the end of the pipeline

the query contains 5 **`$project`** stage, when actually only one is needed. This can add a lot of overhead, especially if applied to a large number of document. 
Instead, use dot notation to query nested fields, for example:

```
{ "$unwind": "$workers.tasks" }
```

### Call `$match` as early as possible

**`$match`** allows to remove some of the documents, so add it as early as possible to apply further aggregation stage on a lower number of documents

### Call `skip` and `$limit` before `$project`

As the query returns only 10 documents, no need to apply the **`$project`** stage on the 180000 other docs

### Properly index the field used for sorting

This is likely to be the bottleneck. Make sure that the field `workers.tasks.start` is indexed ( see [**MongoDB ensureIndex()**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) for details )

### Do not compute the nb of documents returned in the query

Instead of the **`$group`**/**`$unwind`** stage to count matching documents, run another query in the same time for counting only the number of matching documents

---

the main query now looks like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
        "$unwind": "$workers"
    }, {
        "$unwind": "$workers.tasks"
    }, {
        "$match": {
            "workers.tasks.start": {
                "$ne": null
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "workers.tasks.start": 1
        }
    }, {
        "$skip": 0
    }, {
        "$limit": 10
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "task_number": "$workers.tasks.task_number",
            "pieces_actual": "$workers.tasks.pieces_actual",
            "minutes_elapsed": "$workers.tasks.minutes_elapsed",
            "worker_number": "$workers.worker_number",
            "start": "$workers.tasks.start",
            "inbound_order_number": "$workers.tasks.inbound_order_number",
            "pause_from": "$workers.tasks.pause_from",
            "date": "$workers.tasks.date",
            "_id": "$workers.tasks._id",
            "pause_to": "$workers.tasks.pause_to"
        }
    }
])
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/yua7qspo2Jj](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yua7qspo2Jj)

the count query would be

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
        "$unwind": "$workers"
    }, {
        "$unwind": "$workers.tasks"
    }, {
        "$match": {
            "workers.tasks.start": {
                "$ne": null
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$count": "entries_count"
    }
])
```

the count query would look like

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. But after testing the queries you pointed above, I really don't know why the count query is taking 312ms, while the main query is only taking 26ms. What's causing the overhead for the $count?

Comment: @Kais it's hard to say... You may want to take a look a the [`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-explain-option) of the query, this will tell you exactly where mongodb is spending time

Comment: I updated my question in order to provide the results of `explain()`.

Comment: @Ashish currently it's not possible in json mode, but you can achieve this in mgodatagen mode (for example, https://mongoplayground.net/p/yIEueXLsH6R ). If you find any bug, please report them here: https://github.com/feliixx/mongoplayground/issues !