# Mongodb query execution take too much time

Tags: mongodb, go

Iam working on the Go project and I am using mongodb to store my data. But suddenly the mongodb query execution took too much time to get data.
I have a collection named "cars" with around 25000 documents and each document containing around 200 fields (4.385KB). I have an aggregate query like this:

```
db.cars.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "users",
            localField: "uid",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "customer_info"
        }
    },{
        $unwind: "$customer_info"
    },{
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "user_addresses",
            localField: "uid",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "address"
        }
    },{
        $unwind: "$address"
    },{
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "models",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "car_id",
            as: "model_info"
        }
    },{
    $match:{
        purchased_on:{$gt:1538392491}, 
        status:{$in:[1,2,3,4]}, 
        "customer_info.status":{$ne:9}, 
        "model_info.status":{$ne:9},
        }
    },{
        $sort:{
            arrival_time:1
        }
    },{
        $skip:0
    },{
        $limit:5
    }
])
```

My document structure is like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hM-lPwvE45_213rQDYaYuYYbt3LRTgF0/view.

Now, If run this query with out indexing then it take around 10 mins to load the data. Can anyone suggest me how can I reduce its execution time ?

Comment: Your `$match` condition should be at the start of the pipeline to limit the number of document.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet My match filter depend upon the lookup that's why I have added this in the bottom. Or should it be different ? can you suggest with example ?

Comment: Actually `$lookup` stage has been applied to all 25000 document which makes query slow. So to limit the number of document pass through the `$lookup` stage you should use `$match` as soon as possible. Add this at start of the pipeline `{ $match:{
  purchased_on: { $gt:1538392491 }, 
  status: { $in: [1, 2, 3, 4] }, 
}}`...  [Query performance issue for large nested data in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750465/query-performance-issue-for-large-nested-data-in-mongodb/49755301#49755301)

Comment: @Swati could you also post an example document structure and the output that you're trying to get ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar Please check the document structure here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hM-lPwvE45_213rQDYaYuYYbt3LRTgF0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

There are many things to do to optimize your query. What I would try :

- As Anthony Winzlet said in comments, use as possible $match stage as first stage. This way, you can reduce number of documents passed to the following stages, and use indexes.
- Assuming you use at least 3.6 mongo version, change your lookup stages using the 'let/pipeline' syntax ([see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)). This way, you can integrate your 'external filters' (  "customer_info.status":{$ne:9}, "model_info.status":{$ne:9} ) in a $match stage in your lookups pipeline. With indexes on right fields / collections, you will gain some time / memory in your $lookup stages.
- Do your unwind stages as late as possible, to restrict number of documents passed to the following stages.

It's important to understand how works aggregation pipeline : each stage receive data, do its stuff, and pass data to next stage. So the less data is passed to the pipeline, the faster will be your query.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I will implement changes according to your answer.