# Reduce mongodb query (with lookups) execution time

Tags: mongodb

Hello Everyone,

I am working with the mongodb. I have a collection name bookings with total 19,000 documents. My query took 3 sec to execute, I just want only 20 records per query. I have multiple lookup with in the query.

I have added the indexes as follow:

```
{ 
    status: 1, 
    end_date_timestamp: 1, 
    is_visible: 1, 
    arrival_date_time: 1 
}
```

My mongodb query log as below:

```
    { 
        aggregate: "bookings", 
            pipeline: [ 
                { $lookup: 
                    { 
                        localField: "uid", 
                        from: "users", 
                        foreignField: "_id", 
                        as: "customer_info" 
                    } 
                }, 
                { $unwind: "$customer_info" }, 
                { $lookup: 
                    { 
                        foreignField: "_id", 
                        as: "provider_info", 
                        localField: "provider_ids", 
                        from: "users" 
                    } 
                }, 
                { $match: 
                    { status: { $in: [ 0, 6, 7, 8 ] }, 
                    end_date_timestamp: { $gte: 1539839212 }, 
                    is_visible: true, 
                    customer_info.status: { $ne: 9 }, 
                    provider_info.status: { $ne: 9 } } 
                }, 
                { $lookup: 
                    { 
                        localField: "address_id", 
                        from: "user_addresses", 
                        foreignField: "_id", 
                        as: "address" 
                    } 
                }, { $unwind: "$address" }, 
                { $sort: { arrival_date_time: 1 } }, 
                { $skip: 0 }, 
                { $limit: 20 }, 
                { $project: 
                    { 
                        reminder_before_day_hour_time: 0, 
                        customer_info.apt_no: 0, 
                        customer_info.invitation_sent: 0, 
                        provider_info.password: 0, 
                    } 
                } 
            ], 
            cursor: {}, 
            $readPreference: 
            { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, 
            $db: "ironetwork_bk_db" } 
            planSummary: IXSCAN 
            { 
                status: 1, 
                end_date_timestamp: 1, 
                is_visible: 1, 
                arrival_date_time: 1 
            } 
            keysExamined:16281 
            docsExamined:16277 
            hasSortStage:1 
            cursorExhausted:1 
            numYields:183 
            nreturned:20 
            reslen:102932 
            locks:{ 
                Global: 
                    { acquireCount: { r: 97909 } }, 
                Database: 
                    { acquireCount: { r: 97909 } }, 
                Collection: 
                    { acquireCount: { r: 97908 } } 
            } 
            protocol:op_query 3352ms
```

Please suggest me how I can reduce the query execution time?

Comment: Again you are doing same [mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595810/mongodb-query-execution-take-too-much-time). You have to use `$match` asap to limit the number of document pass through the pipeline to reduce the execution time.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have shifted the $match stage at top as possible. My Match stage based on the top lookups result that's why it is on the middle. 2nd point is I have total 19,000 records from which 16,277 are satisfied according to my query and I only return 20 documents. So can you please suggest how I can reduce my execution time?
Because if in future as my records increases then the query execution time also increases

Comment: What version of mongodb you are using?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I am using mongodb 4.0.0

Comment: Great please wait. I will be back in an hour

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Ok I will wait :).

Comment: $lookup is a costly operation. You should always use indexed fields on lookup operations to reduce execution time.