# Mongodb aggregate lookup with pagination is working slow

Tags: mongodb, pagination, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am very new in nodejs and mongodb, below query takes time near by 20 seconds to fetch 10 records only.How can I optimize below query to fetch data quickly? Thanks in advance

```
const skip = pageSize * (pageNo - 1);
const limit = pageSize;

const stages = [
  { $sort : { id : -1 } },
  { $match : { is_active : { $eq : 1 } } },
  { $lookup:{ from: 'offences', localField:'offences', foreignField: 'offence_id', as: 'offenceSetail' } },
  { $project: { 'offences.is_active' : 0, } },
  { $replaceRoot : { newRoot : { $mergeObjects : [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$offenceSetail", 0] }, "$$ROOT"] } } },
  { $project: { 'offenceSetail' : 0 } },
  { $lookup: { from: 'registers', localField: 'user_id', foreignField: 'id', as: 'sender'} },
  { $project: { 'registers.is_active' : 0 } },
  { $replaceRoot : { newRoot : { $mergeObjects : [ { $arrayElemAt: ['$sender', 0] }, "$$ROOT"] } } },
  { $project: { 'sender': 0 } },
  { $facet : { length : [ { $count : "total" }], data : [ { $skip: skip }, {$limit: limit } ] } },
];

Complaint.aggregate(stages)
  .allowDiskUse(true)
  .then(result => {
    return res.status(200).json({
      result: result[0]["data"],
      length: result[0]["length"][0]["total"]
    });
  });
```

sample o/p :

```
length : [{total: 6}],
data: [
{id: 1,create_at: 26-11-2019 12:00, offence: Driving Dangerously, name: Vicky},
{id: 2,create_at: 26-11-2019 12:00, offence: Without Helmet, name: Vikash},
{id: 3 ,create_at: 26-11-2019 12:00, offence: Parking illegal, name: Vishesh},
{id: 4,create_at: 26-11-2019 12:00, offence: Driving Dangerously, name: Shakti},
{id: 5 ,create_at: 26-11-2019 12:00, offence: Without Helmet, name: Rajat},
{id: 6 ,create_at: 26-11-2019 12:00, offence: Parking illegal, name: Nadeem}
]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750465/query-performance-issue-for-large-nested-data-in-mongodb

Comment: @Ashh 
hello Ash Thanks for your time, but did not work as expected, getting total record as 1, Please suggest me some better option. Thanks

Comment: How many documents in the collections?

Comment: @VickyKumar : May be if you can provide sample docs & required o/p, then someone can help you by providing an optimized query, I would say it wouldn't help much if you provide a query & asks for optimization !!

Comment: @prasad_ total documents are 194215

Comment: @srinivasy: I have 3 collection: complaints, offence & users.
 relations are below
 complaints.offences = offences.offence_id
complaints.user_id = users.id
i want result as {complaint.id, complaints.date, offences.offence, users.name} as many records that match the conditions with total documents found

Comment: Here are general guidelines on [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/index.html). As mentioned earlier in the comments, please post sample documents and explain little bit what you are trying to achieve with this query; for example what is the expected result document. Indexes on fields also play a role on query performance. Have you created any indexes on the fields of this collection and what are they? And, generating a query plan can show the index usage. These info is needed for analyzing query performance issues.

Comment: Please, add any additional information within the question post (there is an option to edit your own post).

Comment: @prasad_: I have attached image of sample o/p, Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Please do not post images; post actual text only.

Comment: @prasad_: I have attached sample O/P as text. Please take a look

Comment: @VickyKumar : unless you clearly provide required information asked by users this can't be resolved, Please update this question to get an answer !!!